# Remainder of $(1\cdot2\cdots102)^3$ modulo $105?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble in finding the remainder of $(1\cdot2\cdots102)^3\mod 105$

It is not possible to apply Wilson's Theorem here because 105 is composite. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$105 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7, 102!$ is divisible all of $3,5$ and $7,$ therefore $102!^3$ is divisible $105$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Yes, $105$ is composite. So while you can't use Wilson's theorem, it actually makes the problem a lot *easier*, rather than more difficult. Think about exactly why Wilson's theorem fails for composite numbers: What is $(n-1)!\pmod n$ in those cases?

Comment: I thought of it but I don't know how to follow

Comment: @LuisGimenoSotelo Another hint: $105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$. Now take a close look at your product. What numbers are included there?

Comment: It is ((n-3)!) ^3. But I have tried some examples of composite numbers and I have found no pattern. Is there a pattern?

Comment: @LuisGimenoSotelo Don't write it as $(n-3)!^3$, write it as $1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots$ (don't write all of it, just imagine that you are). Compare what you get there to $105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ and see if you can spot anything. Apart from that, I have given you two substantial hints, and Reinstein has given you the actual answer. I don't know what more to do for you.

Comment: It was very easy when you find that 102! is congruent to 0 (mod 3), to 0 (mod 5) and to 0 (mod 7) and because these numbers are prime to each other, 102! is congruent to 0 (mod 3*5*7). Thank you very much!

Comment: @LuisGimenoSotelo Even that seems like a bit of an over-think for me, personally, but it's correct. You explicitly have $3, 5$ and $7$ appear as terms in $102!$, so $102! = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot \text{something}$, making it congruent to $0$ modulo $105$. There is no need to split into mod 3, 5, 7 and argue about coprimality and stuff.